# Places to make quant code/tools publicly avaliable

Tags: option-pricing, database

Over the years I have developed several tools - including pricing, optimization and calibration tools - most in VBA, C# and C++

I would like to make them publicly avaliable. Aside from putting up my own site what other distribution channels could one use ?
(R has a great platform for package distribution (CRAN) - something like that won't be avaliable for excel-VBA or C# - still, perhaps there is some place online where finance tools tend to cluster)

Comment: is github too general?

Comment: I will have a look at it thank you - If you have any other suggestions just wright them up as an answer ;)  perhaps with some comments on why to use which site et

Comment: you can also use bitbucket for a free private repository.  at github you only get public for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github and Bitbucket are both good options for a git repository.  If you want other people to look at your code and help build on it, Github is the better choice.  If privacy is what matters most, you can get a free private repository from Bitbucket.  On github, only public repositories are free.

Answer (score 0):

volopta.com was suggested in the thread on a page for replication code.

Once your study is published you can add it to the [ReplicationWiki](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de) (that I founded) and give a link to where the code can be accessed. If the publication is covered by RePEc that page then links back to the wiki.

[Runmycode](http://www.runmycode.org/) is a page that can be used to share the code and data that underlie research publications. Several finance papers are already listed.